# What is the proper way to handle concurrency with SQLite3 when writing data from an API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, electron

When using the below API, I need to store returned data from [events](https://dev.mixer.com/reference/chat/events) such as:

- UserJoin
- UserLeave

These events can happen at any time which makes concurrent writing difficult.

```
socket.on('UserJoin', data => {
    // Write data to the database
});

socket.on('UserLeave', data => {
    // Write data to the database
});
```

1. How can I handle concurrency with SQLite3 when I need to write data from [Mixer's API](https://dev.mixer.com/guides/chat/chatbot)?
2. Should something other than SQLite3 be used in my Electron app for this situation?

Comment: "You don't". Sqlite3 is perfect for prototyping, but once you need real database functionality, like proper concurrency handling: switch to a real database. Grab postgres and the node-postgres package, for instance, and start writing reliable database code.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm looking into a server/client database to be used locally now. Could you make this into an answer to be accepted please?

Comment: Doesn't really belong as an answer - there are plenty of posts on SO, and advice on the web as a whole, about using sqlite for more than what it was designed for, and almost all of them already tell the poster to use a real database once you hit the (intentional) limitations of sqlite3. So normally you'd run across that during the [searching and researching](/help/how-to-ask) step of the "what to do _before_ posting a question to SO" work.

Comment: Most of the posts I came across on SO and other sites say that SQLite is perfectly fine for single use offline applications. I found maybe 4 posts about it not being good enough. I went through about 20+ posts before asking so I did plenty of searching and researching before asking.

Comment: Sorry, how is this an offline use case? You're asking about concurrency caused by socket activity. That's most definitely not an offline use case, even if you only run it locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough points to comment so forgive me for distorting my comment into an answer.

SQLite can support limited concurrency in various configurations such as running SQLite in WAL mode and using THREADSAFE=1 or the equivalent config option SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED. This configuration allows for multiple concurrent readers but only one writer at a time. Writes are serialized with blocking so this might not be desirable in your situation if you need simultaneous writes.

There are client-server databases that you can use locally such as MySQL, Faircom, SQL Server, Postgres and many others.